# How to get the colors of bmp with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, bmp

I have taken the follow code [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654480/writing-bmp-image-in-pure-c-c-without-other-libraries) and I am trYing to visualize the colors of an bmp image.

```
    int row_padded = (width*3 + 3) & (~3);
    char* data = new  char[row_padded];
    char tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        fread(data, sizeof( char), row_padded, f);
        for(int j = 0; j < width*3; j += 3) {
            cout << "B: "<< (double)data[j] << " G: " << (double)data[j+1]<< " R: " << (double)data[j+2]<< endl;
        }
    }
```

This is the image: 
[image: This is the image]
However most of the results I get are B:0 G:0 R:0, despite the fact the picture has nothing black on it.
Is this the right way to get the colors?

Comment: I suggest using a library (such as [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h)) instead of parsing the file manually.

Comment: I want to do it without any libraries.

Comment: Then you can look at how stb_image does it, and do something similar.

Comment: It is a PNG image.  Your operating system knows how to read them.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-using-images-bitmaps-and-metafiles-use

Comment: See may answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768094/pointer-file-randomly-changes-value-in-middle-of-reading-raw-bitmap-data which shows how to read a bitmap and how to get the color value of each pixel.

Comment: If you want to do it without using any libraries, then you'll just end up re-implementing the code in those libraries you don't want to use. What's the point? Except for a lot of extra work..

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has iterators, algorithms, and `std::vector`.  The C language doesn't.